# Parse SDK updating date field

Tags: ios, mongodb, parse-platform, swift3

I am using the Parse SDK in iOS which connects my app to a mongo database. I am unable to update a date field. My date field is called "eta".
I know I have the date format correct. Here's my code in Swift:

`parseObject.objectId = "ZzdfGr"
parseObject.setObject("2017-01-12T15:24:50.129Z", forKey: "eta")`

Any other fields I can update, however the date field is not working for me.

Comment: what error are you getting and how are you casting it?

Comment: There is no error coming back. I just see that its not updating the date field if I look in the database.

Comment: I know it's trying to update it though, as I am printing each object to Xcode's console as so:

print ("the parse object is \(parseObject)")

and I see :  

the parse object is <orders: 0x1709a4780, objectId: ZzdfGr, localId: (null)> {
    ACL = "<PFACL: 0x170974560>";
    eta = "2017-01-12T15:24:50.129Z";
}

Comment: Set parse-server logs to verbose=1 and let's what error comes up!

Comment: let me figure out how to do that I am on Heroku . Hold on please!

Comment: I have the error logged: schema mismatch for orders.eta; expected Date but got String

Comment: I know this is the problem, because I have the date in correct format . I don't know how to supply it though to Parse as a date

Comment: You'll need to create a `Date` object corresponding to the date you need.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I know that "2017-01-12T15:24:50.129Z" is exactly the correct date format I need. I just don't know how to send it in the  format not being a string. Im other words, Parse thinks I am trying to send it a string because it's encapsulated in quotes. What I'm looking for is the correct method to amend date fields in Parse so that it knows its a date

Comment: If I look at the raw info inside the database I see that any objects inside my "eta" date field are shown as so: 

 "eta": {
        "$date": "2017-01-12T19:28:00.000Z"
    }

which means that when saving it I also kind of need to save it up in a similar fashion

Comment: Any idea, Estel or @Cliffordwh ?

Comment: post me the variable you casting in swift? becasue you saving it as a string. You need to cast it as! Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So cast it like this for swift3

Just replace the string (2017-01-12T15:24:50.129Z) with your string or varible.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-01-12T15:24:50.129Z")
print("date: \(date)")

parseObject.setObject(date, forKey: "eta")
```